# Trying to read barcodes with Zxing, but it seems the onActivityResult is not beeing called

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

as the title says, I'm trying to scan 1D barcodes, so far I have thet following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    }

    public void test(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "1D_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {  
          switch (requestCode) {
          case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                IntentResult intentResult = 
                   IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

                if (intentResult != null) {

                   String contents = intentResult.getContents();
                   String format = intentResult.getFormatName();

                   TextView uno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                   uno.setText(contents);
                   Toast.makeText(this, "Numero: " + contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Log.d("SEARCH_EAN", "OK, EAN: " + contents + ", FORMAT: " + format);
                } else {
                   Log.e("SEARCH_EAN", "IntentResult je NULL!");
                }
             } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e("SEARCH_EAN", "CANCEL");
             }
         }
    }   
}
```

And of course, I have both IntentResult and IntentIntegrator added to the project.

So, the scanner is beeing called correctly when a button is pressed and it seems to scan the code perfectly (it says "Text found" after it scans it), but it seems that the onActivityResult is not called, since the TextView is not beeing updated and the Toast is not appearing.

Any idea on what the mistake could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first mistake is not using `IntentIntegrator.initiateScan()`, replacing it with your own hand-rolled call to `startActivityForResult()`.

Your second mistake is in assuming that `IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE` is `0`. It is not.

Hence, with your current code, you are sending out a request with request code of `0`, which is coming back to `onActivityResult()` with request code of `0`, which you are ignoring, because you are only looking for `IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE`.

Simply replace the body of your `test()` method with a call to `initiateScan()`, and you should be in better shape. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/ZXing) that demonstrates the use of `IntentIntegrator`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve your same problem so.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView tvStatus, tvResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        this.tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        Button scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                    intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent,
                            IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("BARCODE_ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
                requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (scanResult != null) {

            this.tvStatus.setText(scanResult.getContents());
            this.tvResult.setText(scanResult.getFormatName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be good to explain the change but you have fixed the immediate problem in this snippet for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The onActivityResault function must be overridden. just add an @Override before the function declaration and it will be solved.